# Bitnami Errors on Wordpress Lightsail (AWS)

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I have installed a fresh copy of Lightsail on AWS and just All-In-One Migrated my theme to the new hosting platform. (I'm quite new to both Lightsail and Bitnami).

When I check the Bitnami **Diagnostic|Testing Tool**, I get these warnings, relating to the **All In One Plugin**.

How important are these? And if need too, how do I clear them?

The site is working well, I don't seem to have any permissions issues when moving files, caching the site or installing plugins, and the Wordpress site health is 100% good.

Any explanation on what to do would be great, thank you.

```
[Apache]
Found recent error or warning messages in the Apache error log.

[Wed Aug 03 13:22:03.848176 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1432:tid 
140258548946688] [client **ip_address**:53681] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: 
PHP Notice: Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown 
on line 0', referer: 
https://greenwellies.co.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ai1wm_import

Press [Enter] to continue:

 [Wed Aug 03 13:22:08.443365 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1432:tid 
140258540553984] [client **ip_address**:53681] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: 
PHP Notice: Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown 
on line 0', referer: 
https://greenwellies.co.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ai1wm_import
 [Wed Aug 03 13:22:12.991770 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1432:tid 
140258557339392] [client **ip_address**:53681] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: 
PHP Notice: Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown 
on line 0', referer: 
https://greenwellies.co.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ai1wm_import
```

```
[Wordpress]
Found recent WordPress plugin related error messages in the Apache error log.

[Wed Aug 03 11:31:28.384100 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9111:tid 
140338576348928] [client **ip_address**:52468] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: 
Press [Enter] to continue:

PHP Notice: Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown 
on line 0', referer: https://greenwellies.co.uk/wp-admin/plugin-install.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they're warnings, and everything seems to be working fine, you're probably alright.

What it's probably telling you is there's some sort of problem with writing to the temporary directory WP wants to use, and it had to fall back to the system directory instead. You can look in `php.ini` at the `upload_tmp_dir` and make sure the account you're running these installs with has write access there (and that it exists in the first place).